# How do I output a list of PDF files set up via a custom content type

Tags: views

I set up a custom content type 'yam' where I upload a PDF file. Each file has a language of either "English" or "Spanish", along with a title, like "Winter 2016".

I've been playing with Views, but I cannot get it to output the equivalent of :

```
<a href="URL">Title</a>
```

I can only get a list of Titles or a list of file names URLs like:

`<a href="URL">Filename</a>`

.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: using Drupal 8.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **Formatter** to be *URL to file*

Rewrite the field as attached image using the title to display link to file with the title as link text

[image]

Comment: heh, now how can I display the filesize? =)

Comment: Add a relationship for file then you will find new field called file size use it.
Please do upvote

Comment: Please do upvote